# CMMotionManager Tilt To Move Node Left & Right Swift 4

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cmmotionmanager

I have a separate SKNode class called Balloon which is below.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Balloon: SKNode {
    init(image: SKSpriteNode) {
        super.init()

        let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "balloons")
        var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "red_balloon1"), size: CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = floorCategory
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = floorCategory

        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
        self.zPosition = 1

        for i in 1...atlas.textureNames.count {
            let Name = "red_balloon\(i).png"
            textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
        }

        image.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true)))

        self.addChild(image)
    }

    // Enables the ability to drag the ballon along the x axis
    func move(touchLocation: CGPoint) {
        if self.calculateAccumulatedFrame().contains(touchLocation) {
            self.position.y = touchLocation.y
            self.position.x = touchLocation.x
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I'm then using this class in my GameScene like below.

```
    let balloon = Balloon(image: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red_balloon1"))


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
            self.addChild(balloon)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
            if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
                balloon.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 50, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 50)
       }
}
```

Basically what I basically would like to do is use the application in portrait mode and tile left or right to move the node which ever way I tilted my iPhone. Below is what I used back in Objective C days but I'm not sure how it is with Swift 4 these days or if there's anything better. Hopefully I provided enough info for some tips and anything helps!

```
#define BALLOON 25

    -(void)startAccelerometerData {
        motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1/60.0;
        [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

          valueX = accelerometerData.acceleration.x*26.0;

            newX = (balloon.center.x +valueX);
            if (newX > 320-BALLOON)
                newX = 320-BALLOON;
            else if (newX < 0+BALLOON)
                newX = 0+BALLOON;

            balloon.center = CGPointMake(newX, balloon.center.y);
    } ];
    }
```

Comment: can you confirm that you are getting the accelerometer data? That is, if you have correct numbers coming in when you tilt your device? If you aren't getting correct numbers, then whatever you feed to your physicsBody will be useless.

Comment: @Fluidity It works but it moves the balloon off the screen. I can’t even tilt my phone left and right for it to only move the way I tilted it. I literally put up the app and the balloon flies away and I kinda can move it but if I turn my phone in all these different types of crazy positions

Comment: is it possible your device is malfunctioning? can you test with another? Or can you confirm your device is functioning correctly, by printing the raw data when you tilt left / right?

Comment: @Fluidity I don't think so, I'm sure I would have figured out the obviously troubleshooting errors like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it.

```
if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft {
                balloon.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * -500.0, dy: 0)
            } else {
                balloon.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 500.0, dy: 0)
            }
        }
```